# What's the difference between Printwriter and OutputStream

Tags: java, file-io

First,we have PrintWriter

```
java.io.File f=new java.io.File("s.txt");

   java.io.PrintWriter out=new java.io.PrintWriter(f);

   out.print(5);

   out.print(7);

   out.close();
```

Then we have outputstream

```
 java.io.File f=new java.io.File("s.txt");

 java.io.FileOutputStream out=new java.io.FileOutputStream(f);

   out.write(5);

   out.write(7);

   out.close();
```

Whats the difference?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`OutputStreams` are meant for *binary* data. Writers (including `PrintWriter`) are meant for *text* data.

You may not see the difference in your specific situation as you're calling `PrintWriter.write(int)` which writes a single character - if the character encoding you're using just maps characters to the same byte, for characters less than 127, then you'll see the same result. But if you give it a different encoding, *then* you'll see a difference.

`PrintWriter` is also different in that it suppresses IO exceptions - as does `PrintStream`, which is the binary stream equivalent of `PrintWriter`.

Answer (score 3):

From this [java2novice.com link](http://java2novice.com/java_interview_questions/servlet-outputstream-printwriter-diff/) I extracted the following, that is similar to what Jon said:

**ServletOutputStream:** `ServletResponse.getOutputStream() returns` a `ServletOutputStream`
        suitable for writing binary data in the response. The servlet
        container does not encode the binary data, it sends the raw data
        as it is.

**PrintWriter:** `ServletResponse.getWriter()` returns `PrintWriter` object which sends
        character text to the client. The `PrintWriter` uses the character
        encoding returned by `getCharacterEncoding()`. If the response's
        character encoding has not been specified then it does default
        character encoding.